# Getting Selected Values from Multiple Dropdowns in MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a web application having multiple drop downs. I have used enums in my model to populate these drop down and there is a single from submit button in my view. I am trying to figure out how could I get all the selected Index from these drop down with 1 button click.

My Controller looks something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var model = new DropDownModel();


        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DropDownModel model)
    {
        // Get the selected value
        int id = model.SelectedId;

        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult About()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

DropDown in my view:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.BillTemplate)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),"--BillTemplate--",new { style = "width:108px;font-size:90%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px" })
                  <span style="margin-left:1px"></span>  

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.ReadType)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),"--Read Type--",new { style = "width:70px;font-size:90%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px" })



<input type="submit" value="Submit" hidden="hidden"/>
```

and My Model:

```
namespace BTSWeb.Models
{
public enum States { ANY, FL, TX, GA, NE };
public enum PaymentType { ANY, Email, Paper, No };

public class DropDownModel 
{

public int SelectedId { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Comment: you have to pass value as well you are currently only passing Text of SelectList item

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, also will that solve getting the values from all of my dropdowns and not just one?

Comment: ``e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }`` you are not passing value ``e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value="1" }``

Comment: actually select list item value is posted on action

Comment: I would check out ViewModels. They will help you greatly. Gave a sample below using mostly your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using DropDownModel as your view model. You will only ever be able to populate on selectedID using this.  What you need to do is somehting like

```
public class ViewModel 
{

public int SelectedStateId { get; set; }
public int SelecPaymentTypeId { get; set; }


}
```

then in your controller you would pass in

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel()
return View(ViewModel);
```

and on your view you would have

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId, Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.BillTemplate)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),"--BillTemplate--",new { style = "width:108px;font-size:90%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px" })
                  <span style="margin-left:1px"></span>  

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelecPaymentTypeId , Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.ReadType)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),"--Read Type--",new { style = "width:70px;font-size:90%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px" })
```

and finally on your controller post method you would have

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModelmodel)
    {
        // Get the selected value
        int id = model.SelectedStateId;
        int id2 = model.SelecPaymentTypeId;

        return View();
    }
```